# Display audio file in frontend through axios get request. Nodejs Reactjs Mongodb , multer , Gridfs

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, multer, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

I used mongodb , gridfs ,multer to store the audio file.
And need to show the audio file in reactjs frontend through axios.

```
app.get('/songs/getsong/:filename', (req, res) => {

  console.log(req.params.filename);
    const file = gfs
    .find({
      filename: req.params.filename
    })
    .toArray((err, files) => {
      if (!files || files.length === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          err: "no files exist"
        });
      }
      gfs.openDownloadStreamByName(req.params.filename).pipe(res);
      console.log(files)
      return res.status(200);
    });  
});
```

Display audio file in frontend

```
import React, { useEffect ,useState} from 'react'
import Header from '../header/Header';
import "./home.css"
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Home(){

    const [audiofile , setAudioFile] = useState()
 

   
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/songs/getsong/379500b35576a4c49792718aebfc27ef.mp3')
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setAudioFile(res)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    });


    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <form action="http://localhost:8000/songs/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h1>File Upload</h1>
                <input id="file" type="file" accept="audio/*" name='file' />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>

            <audio
                controls
                src={audiofile}>
                Your browser does not support the
                <code>audio</code> element.
            </audio>
   
        </div>
    )
    
}
```

this is the file request

```
   {
        _id: 60774f8560de1713d4b06234,
        length: 11756413,
        chunkSize: 261120,
        uploadDate: 2021-04-14T20:25:25.300Z,
        filename: '379500b35576a4c49792718aebfc27ef.mp3',
        md5: '36d8d712eb886859b07952e49d4de6a6',
        contentType: 'audio/mpeg'
      }
```

> In postman it showed a audio file and it works fine. I need to show it
> on frontend.

[Check Postman response ss here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPoiv.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Locally, you can use the HTML5 [Audio tag](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) to play the audio, feed src with URL of the audio and , that's it.

Comment: how to get the audio from backend server ? and play the audio

Comment: You have to send the streams of chunks from the backend. Make a new route /getAudio or something, obtain the audio you have stored and then send the streams in chunks. You can use send-seekable in npm package to send streams of audio.

Comment: can u suggest some reference to get clarified on sending streams of chunks.i don't know how to send this?

Answer (score 0):

its probably not playing because you are setting audio file with res instead of `res.data`, then confirm the format of the response. its usually in binary format so you need to convert before playing, you can `blob()` and `URL.createObjectURL()`